# Laravel blade template: check record exist in pivot table

Tags: laravel, pivot, laravel-blade

I have two models which are joined by a pivot table(taxrule_rates), TaxRule(table tax_rules) and TaxRate(table tax_rates)
Now in blade template dropdown, what is the way to check tax-rate record is exists in pivot table for respective models. I want pre selected taxrate options on dropdown for a taxrule.

edit_taxrule blade Dropdown is :

```
@foreach($taxrates as $taxrate)
   <option value="{{$taxrate->id}}" >{{$taxrate->rate_name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

In TaxRuleController :

```
 $taxrule = $TaxRule::find($id);
 $taxrates = TaxRate::get();
```

Comment: You can check with relation of that table. for example if $taxRule->TaxRuleRates->count() > 0 then pivot table has some records.

Comment: @KashifSaleem count is ok, but in above dropdown how show selected taxrate

Comment: i got this trick @if($rule->taxrates()->where('taxrule_rates.rate_id', $taxrate->id)->exists()) selected @endif. , but i want more specific solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller**

```php
$taxrule = TaxRule::find($id);
$taxrates = TaxRate::get();
$taxrateIds = $taxrule->taxRates()->pluck('id')->toArray(); // it will work if u set realtionship
```

---

**Model**

in `TaxRule` model

```php
public function taxRates()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\TaxRate', 'taxrule_rates');
}
```

---

**Blade**

```php
@foreach($taxrates as $taxrate)
    <option value="{{$taxrate->id}}" 
        {{ in_array($taxrate->id,$taxrateIds) ? 'selected' : '' }}
        >{{$taxrate->rate_name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

## one more solution

**Model**

in `TaxRule` model

```php
protected $appends = ['selecteded'];

public function taxRates()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\TaxRate', 'taxrule_rates');
}

public function getSelectededAttribute()
{
     return $this->taxRates()->pluck('id')->toArray();
}
```

---

**Blade**

```php
@foreach($taxrates as $taxrate)
    <option value="{{$taxrate->id}}" 
        {{ in_array($taxrate->id,$taxrate->selecteded) ? 'selected' : '' }}
        >{{$taxrate->rate_name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: $taxrate->has('TaxRateRules') will give true if  taxrate has taxrule(s) but above dropdown is in taxtrule edit blade and taxrate should be selected if it has current taxtrule(which taxrule is being edited).... please read question carefully

Comment: @SuryaprakashPatel can u mention you'r database table structure .?

Comment: @SuryaprakashPatel sorry now i got your question u can check now it should work if u set `belongsToMany()`

Answer (score 0):

As Kashif mentioned on the comments, you can use the `count` function to check whether there's any relation between the models or not.

To pre-select the one which has a relation, you could do something like this:

```
@foreach($taxrates as $taxrate)
    @if($taxrate->TaxRateRules->count() > 0)
        <option selected value="{{$taxrate->id}}" >{{$taxrate->rate_name}}</option>
    @else
        <option value="{{$taxrate->id}}" >{{$taxrate->rate_name}}</option>
    @endif
@endforeach
```